# How can I reverse the order of HTML DOM elements inside a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to print out receipts that inserted into my database, and the latest receipt should be on the top of my page. But when I query my database, I store all the data inside a var s, and naturally it will make the data that was inserted earliest on the top of my page, how do I reverse this?

```
function querySuccess(tx, results){
    if(results.rows.length == 0)
    {
        $("#ReceiptsList").html("<p>You have no receipts captured yet</p>");
    }
        else
    {
        var s = "";
        for(var i = 0; i<results.rows.length; i++)
        s += "<a href='edit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id+"'><strong><font size = 3> " + results.rows.item(i).name +"<font></strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size = 1>Date:" +results.rows.item(i).date +  "<font></a> ";
    }
        //I tried s.reverse(); but didn't work, nothing was showed on the page
        $("#ReceiptsList").html(s);
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript -> changed tags

Comment: Could you not query your database differently so that `results` contains the results in reverse-insertion order? Seems like ordering would be done more efficiently in a database query than by re-ordering the DOM via JavaScript.

Comment: 1999 called, they want the font tags back. Use CSS for styles, not deprecated tags.

Comment: @qwrqwr, originally your tags were "Java jQuery", Puce updated them so that they are now "javascript jQuery"

Comment: @qwrqwr It was Java, [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11197179/revisions) shows it.

Comment: bugs??I am 100% sure that I have js on the tags from the beginning....but anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the loop? Start at the end?

```
for(var i = results.rows.length-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Or append the beginning of the string, not the end!

Or have the server return the correct order in the first place.

Comment: +1 for "have the server return the correct order in the first place."

Comment: In other words: *anything* but reordering the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
function querySuccess(tx, results){
if(results.rows.length == 0)
{
    $("#ReceiptsList").html("<p>You have no receipts captured yet</p>");
}
    else
{
    var s = "";
    for(var i = results.rows.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    s += "<a href='edit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id+"'><strong><font size = 3> " + results.rows.item(i).name +"<font></strong>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size = 1>Date:" +results.rows.item(i).date +  "<font></a> ";
}

    $("#ReceiptsList").html(s);
}
```